# Flutter Vertical viewport was given unbounded height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to build a dynamic list view based on a date selection and upon that I will call an api to get the data and populate the list accordingly. Then in the list view itself towards the end I have a down button which I press should open an expansion panel.So to do a the list I call a function Widget buildDynamicList(BuildContext context) to dynamically fill the new list based on the new data. I am getting this errors.

```
I/flutter ( 3438): The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
I/flutter ( 3438): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
I/flutter ( 3438): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a vertical
I/flutter ( 3438): viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
I/flutter ( 3438): typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
```

In the first column as below I draw a Card and in it I will select the date and the next column below I will call this function `buildDynamicList(context)`

```
 new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                                margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 0, 0),
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                                           color:Color.fromRGBO(36, 46, 66, 1),
                                                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                                                            topLeft: const Radius.circular(35),
                                                            bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(35)
                                                          ),

                                                          ),
                                width: double.infinity,
                                height: 55.0,

                                //child:Expanded(
                                child:Card(

                                color: Color.fromRGBO(36, 46, 66, 1),
                                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35) 
                                ),

                                child: Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      height: 40.0,
                                      width: 50.0,

                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                      border: new Border.all(
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                        width: 2.5,
                                      ),
                                      ),
                                      child: Icon(
                                                              Icons.calendar_today,
                                                              size: 25.0,
                                                              color: Colors.white,
                                                            ),
                                      ),
                                      Expanded(

                                        child:
                                        Column(
                                          //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, 
                                          children: [ 
                                          //new Row( 
                                          // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, 

                                          //children: <Widget>[ 
                                          new Text( 
                                          "From", style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),
                                          ), 
                                          new Text( 
                                          "01 Jan 2019", style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),
                                          ), 
                                        // new Icon(Icons.account_circle) 
                                          //style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2 

                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Expanded(

                                        child:
                                        Column(
                                          //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, 
                                          children: [ 
                                          //new Row( 
                                          // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, 

                                          //children: <Widget>[ 
                                          new Text( 
                                          "To", style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),
                                          ), 
                                          new Text( 
                                          "02 Jan 2019", style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),
                                          ), 
                                        // new Icon(Icons.account_circle) 
                                          //style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2 

                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],

                                )
                                ),
                                //)

                        ),
                      ]

                  ),       
                  new Column(

                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

                      children: <Widget>[
                        buildDynamicList(context)

                      ],

                  )
```

Here is the function which I call for dynamic list . I have tried many options e.g. Expanded, Flexible etc all giving me errors.

```
Widget buildDynamicList(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
                    //decoration: new BoxDecoration(border: new Border.all(width: 2.0)),
                    height:200,

                      //fit: FlexFit.loose ,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        //  shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: vehicles.length,                      
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {

                               return new ListView(
                                 children: <Widget>[
                               new Text("TEE"),
                                 ] 


                               );
                          }

                     ),
                    );

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the nested `listview` as it is unnecessary:

```
   Widget buildDynamicList(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
                //decoration: new BoxDecoration(border: new Border.all(width: 2.0)),
                height:200,
                //fit: FlexFit.loose ,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    //shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: vehicles.length,                      
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                           return Text("TEE"),
                      }
                   ),
                );
             }
```

Comment: I removed it works but now I dont want to set the height at 200. I want it to be dynamic. Actually what was the problem withe the listview

Comment: `Listviews` are widgets which inherit size from its parent widget, the nested one wasn't able to get `height` for its direct parent which is a `Listview`. If you want it to work the wrapping it with `Container` like the parent one would fix the problem.

Comment: If you want the height to be proportionate to screen size you can use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /2` for example.

Comment: I did remove the container and put expanded did not work. But I tried this one   return new Flexible( it works. Does this help cause my list could go beyond the screen size. So how will MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /2 help ?

Comment: `Expandable` also inherits its size from parent, unlike `Flexible` which takes its size from its children widgets. `MediaQuery` will change the size depending on The screen size and orientation in some cases.

Comment: So is it safe to use Flexible or should I go with the container and set the height as MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189674/discussion-between-mazin-ibrahim-and-newbie).